# What is loaded in first frame?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm building a flash game wish contains sounds/images/videos and such. Now I want to build a preloader for this game. The problem is that currently it is around 2 mb of data in the first frame. How can I see wish objects that are being loaded in the first frame?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the IDE you can generate a size report.

- Make sure nothing is selected on stage.
- In the properties panel next to **Profile : Default** click **Edit**
- At the very bottom and the heading **Advanced** there is a checkbox labeled **Generate size report**.

When you run your file the size report will be displayed in the output panel and I think a log file is also saved.
I don't know if this will give you the information you want though.

You could also have a look at this article which has a good method for preloading.
http://www.8bitrocket.com/2008/4/22/Tutorial-Preloading-Actionscript-3-AS3-Games-in-Flash-CS3/
Basically you just put all your assets on the second frame so that the preloader will load first.